# Coldfusion file generation with crlf delimiter

Tags: coldfusion

is there a fast way to change a file end line delimiter?

I am coding in coldfusion and I use the following code to generate a file:

```
    <cfset Header='#CODFIC_H##CODENR_H##SOCEMET_H##SOCDEST_H##SEQFIC_H##NBENR_H##DTTRAN_H##VERSION_H##evaluate(libre_H)#'>
<cfset NewFile = FileOpen('#ArchiveSAVPath#\#SAVFileName#','Append')>
<cfset fileWriteLine(NewFile, Header)>
<cfloop query="GetAccountList">
     <cfset Detail='#CODFIC_D##CODENR_D##evaluate(MARQUE_D)##evaluate(NUMFAC_D)##FILLER1_D##NOLITI_D##ETALIT_D##FILLER2_D##TYPDEM_D##TXT130_1_D##evaluate(TXT130_2_D)##evaluate(FILLER3_D)#'>
    <cfset fileWriteLine(NewFile, Detail)>
</cfloop>
```

The default Delimiter when we use fileopen is lf. I want to generate the file with a crlf delimiter.

Can anyone have a solution with  good performance?

Thanks

Comment: Two things you can do to improve efficiency are:  first find a way to not use evaluate.  2nd, use cfsavecontent to generate the data to be appended to the file, and then append it with cffile.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the attribute addNewLine="false" to the line in which you create your file object then just manually append the end of line characters you want to the end of your  line.

e.g.

```
 <cfset LF = chr(13) & chr(10)>
 <cfset Detail='#CODFIC_D##CODENR_D#' & LF>
```